# draw rectangle where cursor is

Tags: c#, drawrectangle

I'm trying to draw a circle and a rectangle when the mouse is clicked so I got the x and y cords of the mouse click.

I've searched on the internet that in C# this can only be done with Margin, there is no origin or something like in java, you could give x and y to the constructor.

Now I'm trying to set this right but I can't figure out how to calculate this properly:

According to this:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

rec.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0,0, 0);
```

Can someone help me? Or is it not possible with this?

Comment: You can use a Canvas to position FrameworkElements and Controls with absolute coordinates. You can also override the OnRender method.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Is this WPF or Windows Forms? WPF mouse event args have a `GetPosition(UIElement)` method which will tell you the mouse coordinates relative to the control you pass in. So if you're trying to draw a rectangle on a `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` called `MyCanvas` you can use the `Point` returned by `e.GetPosition(MyCanvas)` to place your rectangle.

Here's an example:

```
void MyCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point ClickPoint = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
    Rectangle Rectangle = new Rectangle();
    System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetTop(Rectangle, ClickPoint.Y)
    System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetLeft(Rectangle, ClickPoint.X)
    MyCanvas.Children.Add(Rectangle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually it is a WPF touch table ( surface ), but I think the principle is the same or not?

Comment: I don't know. That's pretty relevant information you should post in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
void MyCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point ClickPoint = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
    Rectangle Rectangle = new Rectangle();
    System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetTop(Rectangle, ClickPoint.Y)
    System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetLeft(Rectangle, ClickPoint.X)
    MyCanvas.Children.Add(Rectangle);
}
```

Thanks to spencer.